# Object in Domain: Dealing with Set Theory

Tags: logic

Consider the following
Proposition:

- Let $A\subseteq B$. Also, let $B\subseteq C$. Thus, $A\subseteq C$.

Proof:

- Let $A\subseteq B$. Also, let $B\subseteq C$.

  > **What goes here?** Assume $x\in A$. As $x\in A$ and $A\subseteq B$, $x\in B$.
  >   As $x\in B$ and $B\subseteq C$, $x\in C$.

**Is it that we should let $x$ be an arbitrary element in the domain? But what domain?**

Comment: This is typically done by writing "let $x \in A$ be arbitrary. Then... [proof]... so $x \in C$. Since $x$ was arbitrary, it is true for all $x \in A$".

Comment: I am rather unclear what your question is here ... what is the relevance of the biconditional with the existential at the start of your post?  But as far as the universal goes at the end of your post: see Bill's comment above.

Comment: The question is bold. When saying let $x\in A$, I interpret it as $\forall x\in A$ which is not correct, because by assumption $x\in A$ which would be tied to the iff statement in the beginning. That is why I had the iff in the beginning.

Comment: I edited the question since then for clarity purposes.

Comment: "But what domain?"  $A$.  If you put things in terms of domains, then the domain is $A$.  Why was there ever any question about that?

Comment: I am assuming the domain is the universal set, but I am not sure.

Comment: Maybe, saying let x be an arbitrary element would be better, but I am not sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Proof:
>
> - Let $A\subseteq B$. Also, let $B\subseteq C$. Assume $x\in A$. Thus,
>   $x=a$ for some $a\in A$.  As $x\in A$ and $A\subseteq B$, $x\in B$.
>   As $x\in B$ and $B\subseteq C$, $x\in C$.

Two comments:

First, there is no need for the:

> Thus, $x=a$ for some $a\in A$.

line in your proof. Indeed, notice that you don't use this $a$ later in your proof anyway. Instead, can do it all by reference to $x$, i.e. you can do:

> Proof:
>
> - Let $A\subseteq B$. Also, let $B\subseteq C$. Assume $x\in A$. As $x\in A$ and $A\subseteq B$, $x\in B$.
>   As $x\in B$ and $B\subseteq C$, $x\in C$.

Second, to get the universal in there, simply do:

> - Let $x$ be some arbitrary object from the domain. Let $A\subseteq B$. Also, let $B\subseteq C$. Assume $x\in A$. As $x\in A$ and $A\subseteq B$, $x\in B$.
>   As $x\in B$ and $B\subseteq C$, $x\in C$. Since $x$ was arbitrary, we thus have that for any $x$: if $x \in A$ then $x \in C$. Hence, $A \subseteq C$

Comment: By saying let $x$ be some arbitrary object from the domain, what domain are you referring to out of curiosity? Also, can I get rid of the words some here to avoid ambiguity with the existential quantifier or is it needed?

Comment: @W.G. when you talk about sets $A$, $B$, and $C$, presumably those are all subsets of some larger domain, e.g. they can all be sets of numbers, in which case the domain is numbers. Also, instead of 'some' you could use 'a' ... maybe that helps?  But the whole point is that you pick *one*, though *arbitrary* object. So if you then show something to be true for that object, you will have shown it for *any* arbitrary object, and hence for *all* objects.

Comment: This was very helpful. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Why are you talking of domains?  There's no functions involved.

These are sets.  Sets are collections of elements[*].

$A \subset B$ means all the elements of $A$ are elements of $B$.  so if $A \subset B$ and $B\subset C$ then all the elements of $A$ are elements of $B$.  And as they are elements of $B$ and $B\subset C$ they must also be elements of $C$.  So all elements of $A$ are elements of $C$.  So $A \subset C$.

That's all there is to it.

Now when we do a proof by "element chasing".  The entire idea is that if we pick an *arbitrary* element then because it was arbitrary with no particular special powers, whatever we can conclude about it, we can conclude about all elements.

So if $x \in A$ then ... $x \in B$ because *all* elements of $A$ are elements of $B$.  That's what subsets mean.  And if $x \in B$ then $x \in C$ because *all* elements of $B$ or elements of $C$.  That's what subsets mean.

And if $x \in C$ and there was nothing special or distinguishable about $x$ then *all* elements of $A$ are in $C$.

So $A \subset C$.

That's all there is to it.

....

[*] And $x$ is in the set $A$.  If you need to consider something to be a "domain" (what does "domain" mean in this context?  If it means anything, it means the set that is the subject of our statement) it is $A$.  $A$ is the "domain".  (This isn't wrong.  $A$ is the subject of our statement.  But I find this language about "domains" to be obfuscating at best.)

Comment: I understand you completely when you say: "the entire idea is that if we pick an arbitrary element then because it was arbitrary with no particular special powers, whatever we can conclude about it, we can conclude about all elements." But is there a concise way of notating that?

Comment: What's wrong with $\forall x\in A$??? You say in your comment that is incorrect but I can not understand your reasons for saying so.

Comment: I don't think you need notation as this is the standard interpretation of "Let $x\in A$".  You'd need notation if you mean $x$ was anything *but* arbitrary.... You aren't aren't making your concern very clear.  Are you trying to reestablish ZFC from the ground up on your own?  Otherwise, I'm kind of lost on what exactly the issue is.

Comment: I am not trying to reestablish ZFC from the ground up; I am just trying to understand logic behind the universal quantifier in this context. The axiom I use for subset is the following which is all I believe that is needed: $\forall x, [x\in A\rightarrow x\in B]$. I don't know why saying "let $x\in A$" is needed in the part where I say what goes here. I must have misinterpreted what you were explaining earlier, because I thought you wanted "let $x$ be an arbitrary object" to go there. So, say $x\notin A$ as it could by being arbitrary, the assumption $x\in A$ would be false

Comment: So, $x\in A\rightarrow x\in B$ would hold true vacuously.

Comment: I was thinking about this question some more the other day. You were right to say let $x\in A$, because $\forall x, [x\in A\rightarrow x\in B]\equiv \forall x\in A, x\in B$. This response was helpful too, and I would give this answer to you too if I could. Thank you!